# Angular 2: self.context.data.style is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am loading using a service to load my json data on the app component.

```
this.data = this.dataService.getData()
 .subscribe(
    data => {
     this.data = data;
     this.ui = this.data.style;
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('Data loaded')

 );
```

When I try to access this.ui in the template component for NgStyle, I get the error "Self.context.ui is undefined". Its strange because it shows in the console, but once I add it on my component, it freaks out.

This code is in the app component, I am trying to have dynamic styles from my json

```
<h1 [NgStyle]="{'color': ui.colors.first}"> Random text </h1>
```

Here is the json structure, it looks something like this.

```
{
 "style":{
   "colors": {
      "first": "#ffffff"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really know why angular won't let me use the data, what do you think is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried using the safe nav operator? Like this: `ui?.colors?.first`

Comment: it should be `[ngStyle]` instead of `[NgStyle]` as well.

Comment: it should be `ui.style.colors.first`

Comment: @RomanC no, she (I assume) has declared `this.ui = this.data.style;` in her subscription :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `self.context` error is here:

```
this.data = this.dataService.getData()
```

should be just:

```
this.dataService.getData()
 .subscribe(
    data => {
     this.data = data;
     this.ui = this.data.style;
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('Data loaded')
 );
```

You are assigning data to `this.data` inside `this.data` so that's why it's complaining about `self.context`.

and `[NgStyle]` should be `[ngStyle]` and like @echonax suggested you might have to use safe operators.

Comment: I tried the safe nav operators, and it worked perfectly. What are safe  operators? What do they do? Never have I heard of them before.

Comment: @LadyT they are basicly `if` checks to understand if the object is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @echonax Thank you for the clarification.